# how to load page in div onclick in yii?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

I want to load a page in a certain div by using jquery function `.load()`, here is my code:

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;" id="generalinfo">
    <div class="row alert alert-danger">
        <h4 class="text-center">General Info</h4>
    </div>
</a>

<div class="col-lg-6" id="userbody"></div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#generalinfo').click(function(){

            $('#userbody').load('<?php echo Yii::app()->basePath."/views/users/_generalinfo.php"; ?>');

        });
    });

</script>
```

the page didn't load in the div and there are no errors appeared, so where is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

instead to execute:
    $('#userbody').load('basePath."/views/users/_generalinfo.php"; ?>');

try to call:

```
$('#userbody').load('http://yousthost:portno/views/users/_generalinfo.php');
```

The jquery cannot evalutes on client side the PHP code echo Yii::app()->basePath

Try for instance to save the content of the PHP basepath server side in a javascript variable and the use it, like

```
$('#userbody').load(basePath + '/views/users/_generalinfo.php');
```

while on the server side, while building the html in the javascript section write:
    var basePath = echo Yii::app()->basePath;

hope it's usefull

Comment: same result, the page didn't load